# How to make a color scheme for sub sites

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, less-mixins

I have a question on how to set up a clever way of making a theme of some sort. I'm working with Bootstrap 3.3.7 and less. The challenge is this:

I have a company website with three departments. Each department has its own color. This color is used in the logo and on the links, and maybe on other elements.

The company has some base styling, but when the visitor navigates to one of the department web pages, the color of the logo and links should change to its department colors.

Say, the rules are like this:

- base color = black
- dept_one = red
- dept_two = green
- dept_three = orange

How can this be set up using less and variables?

Technically, when loading one of the sub department's pages, a "department class" is added to the `<body>` tag, so I'm looking for a neat way to structure my less in order to only change the colors one place.

So if I have this html:

```
<body class="dept_one">
```

then I would like to be able to do:

```
a {
  color: @link-color;
}
```

which will produce

```
a {
  color: red; 
}
```

and

```
<body class="dept_two">
```

still using

```
a {
  color: @link-color;
}
```

which in this case will produce

```
a {
  color: green; 
}
```

and so on...

The solution we have today is that a specific department stylesheet is loaded which overwrites the base styling, but I would like to move away from that approach.
I was hoping that with less there would be a clever way to do this like a mixin that will generate these color variables?

Comment: have you using image for logo

Comment: Yes, I didn't specify that it's the background color - behind the image. But in theory I would like to be able to use this color variable anywhere, and it would render the right department color. :-)

Comment: Can you use different stylesheets for evry department page?

Comment: That's what we have today, and what I would like to avoid. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example, [Sample Pen](http://codepen.io/YaserAliPeedikakkal/pen/bZOpVY) you can create your own styles like this

HTML

```
<div class="dep-one">
 <a href="#"> Click here </a>
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
</div>
<div class="dep-two">
  <a href="#"> Click here </a>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
</div>
<div class="dep-three">
  <a href="#"> Click here </a>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</p>
</div>
```

LESS

```
@dep-one: red;
@dep-two: green;
@dep-three: orange;

.dep-one {
  color: @dep-one;
  a {
    color: @dep-one;
  }
}
.dep-two {
  color: @dep-two;
  a {
    color: @dep-two;
  }
}
.dep-three {
  color: @dep-three;
  a {
    color: @dep-three;
  }
}
div {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```